# Bundle products and recurring billing

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, inventory, billing, recurring, billing-agreements

So i'm very new to Magento. I am struggling to find a way to manage my inventory effectively.

My store has a bunch of simple products for sale. I want to take two of these products, create a bundle product and offer this bundle with a monthly billing agreement where the customer gets the product sent to them each month. The issue I'm having is for the first month, I want to the customer to receive both products, but for the recurring months, I only want them to receive one product.

Is there a way to do this in Magento? Currently I have the product I want to bundle as a simple product and having to keep track of my inventory manually and check to see if it's the customers first order so I know to send them both products.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

And because you can't buy recurring items and normal items together, you can't either implement something which adds the simple item as recurring starting next month...